# QR code for vcard prepared in iPhone not recognised by Android device

Tags: ios, qr-code

I have implemented an iPhone QR code generator. Its works well for e-mail, URLs, text, etc. I ran into an issue when I tried to tie in vcards, though.

I used the format:

```
@"BEGIN:VCARD VERSION:2.1 N:Satya;Dash;;; ADR;DOM;PARCEL;HOME:;;**** Mission Street;Cuttack City;Orissa;94014;INDIA. EMAIL;INTERNET:satya@domain.com TEL;CELL:22-122-4567 TEL;CELL:133-156-3345  END:VCARD"
```

The QR code works well in my  iPhone QR code reader (with an alert of some information mission, that is understood). However, an Android QR code scanner does not read it. Why?

Comment: Can you provide us with a copy of the image?

Comment: Your vCard appears to be missing newlines?  There must be a newline after every property.  vCard uses the "\r\n" newline sequence.

Comment: @Michael could you please rewrite the values in your specific format for me...Please

Answer (score 2):

Your vCard should look like this:

```
@"BEGIN:VCARD\r\nVERSION:2.1\r\nN:Satya;Dash;;;\r\nADR;DOM;PARCEL;HOME:;;****Mission Street;Cuttack City;Orissa;94014;INDIA.\r\nEMAIL;INTERNET:satya@domain.com\r\nTEL;CELL:22-122-4567\r\nTEL;CELL:133-156-3345\r\nEND:VCARD"
```